# How can I display a certain sector like 56 on partition 1 from disk /dev/sda?

Tags: partitioning, fdisk

I need to use some commands to help me show what I have in sector 56 on patition 1 form the /dev/sda disk.
Can you please help me.
I don't know if is something linked with fdisk command or not.
Thanks!

Comment: Please tell us the reason, or problem, that you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a sector-size of 512 Bytes you may use the following command to display the content of the 56th sector:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 skip=55 count=56 | hexdump -C
```